# Wanting to input bowling scores, total, average them

Tags: python

Need for a user to input bowling scores and store them, to be totaled and averaged later and they can press "q" or "Q" to quit and total/average them.  I've tried fumbling around figuring out loops but not sure how to deal with inputting integers and also accepting "Q" to stop loop.  Thanks for any help.

```
nums = []
scores = ""

while scores != 'q'.lower():
    scores = input("Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: ")
    if scores != 'q':
        nums.append(int(scores))

    elif scores == 'q'.lower():
        print("quitting")
        break
    scores = int()
    def Average(nums):
        return sum(nums) / len(nums)
    total = sum(nums)
print(f"The total score is: {total}")
average = Average(nums)
print("The score average is: ", round(average, 2))
```

Getting error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ryaber/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 11, in 
scores = input("Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: ")
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'q' is not defined

So not sure how to allow it to accept "Q" to stop loop and total/average them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `.lower()` in `q.lower()` and move it and make it to `score.lower()`.
   So if user types in `q` or `Q` both will be accepted as quit
2. You do not need average function or `while scores != 'q'`  instead you could change it to something simple

So complete code -

```
nums = []
scores = ""

while True:
    scores = input("Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: ")
    if scores.lower() != 'q':
        nums.append(int(scores))

    elif scores.lower() == 'q':
        print("quitting")
        break
    scores = int()
    total = sum(nums)
    
print(f"The total score is: {total}")
average = total/len(nums)
print("The score average is: ", round(average, 2))
```

Result:

```
Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: 25
Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: 32
Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: Q
quitting
The total score is: 57
The score average is:  28.5
```

Edit -
While this may be complicated, this will solve your problem -

```
nums = []
scores = ""

while True:
    scores = input("Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: ")
    try: # This will run when scores is a number
        scores = int(scores)

        if scores.lower() == type(0):
            nums.append(int(scores))

    except: # Will run when it is a alphabet

        if scores.lower() == 'q':
            print("quitting")
            break

        else:
            continue

    scores = int()
    total = sum(nums)
    
    print(f"The total score is: {total}")
    average = total/len(nums)
    print("The score average is: ", round(average, 2))

    break
```

Comment: Hmm this isn't letting me enter in any numbers now

Comment: Thank you, sorry I figured out I was using an old interpreter lol

Comment: Lol, Welcome :D

Comment: Do you know how to not accept scores accidentally over 300 (max bowling score is 300) and make it so it just continues the loop to enter a valid score then (so it'll also only count valid scores in calcs)?  Also, so accidentally pressing Enter won't cause an error and code to crash

Comment: I figured out how to not store/count numbers > 300, just need to accept Enter without an actual input and not crashing code/loop/giving an Error.

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
nums.append(int(scores))
```

just cast it to an int ...

Answer (score 0):

You only need to convert your input string to an int before storing it:

```
nums = []
scores = ""

while scores != 'q'.lower():
    scores = input("Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: ")
    if scores != 'q':
        nums.append(int(scores))

    elif scores == 'q'.lower():
        print("quitting")
        break

def Average(nums):
    return sum(nums) / len(nums)
total = sum(nums)
print(f"The total score is: {total}")
average = Average(nums)
print("The score average is: ", round(average, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append integral value of score to the list

```py
nums.append(int(scores))
```

Also, I guess you might want to use a f-string here

```py
print(f"The total score is: {total}")
```

EDIT :

```py
if scores.lower() != 'q':
    nums.append(int(scores))

elif scores.lower() == "q":
    print("quitting")
    break
```

As pointed out by @PCM, you need to use the `.lower()` method on the variable

The final working code :

```py
nums = []
scores = ""

while scores != 'q':
    scores = input("Please enter a score (xxx) or 'q' to exit: ")
    if scores.lower() != 'q':
        nums.append(int(scores))

    elif scores.lower() == "q":
        print("quitting")
        break
scores = int()
def Average(nums):
    return sum(nums) / len(nums)
total = sum(nums)
print(f"The total score is: {total}")
average = Average(nums)
print("The score average is: ", round(average, 2))
```

You can read more about f-strings [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#:%7E:text=Also%20called%20%E2%80%9Cformatted%20string%20literals%2C%E2%80%9D%20f-strings%20are%20string,runtime%20and%20then%20formatted%20using%20the%20__format__%20protocol.)

Comment: You do not need `'q'.lower()` when it is already a lower character.